# Battery options for 500mA load

Tags: power-supply, batteries, current, supercapacitor

I need to energize a load with 500mA current for 10 seconds. Voltage doesn't needs to be constant but can be in between 0.1v to 1v. The application has size constraints so I can only use a button cell battery (12mm*10mm max). This is demonstrated in figure below for your understanding. I have following questions,

1. Is there any high drain button/coin cell battery with 500mA or more drain current?
2. Can we use a current booster circuit or supercapacitor which can store power from a button cell over time and then apply to the load with 500mA current for 10 seconds?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Best regards,
MR

Comment: This sounds challenging. What voltage does the load need? Does it have to be constant, or can it decay during the 10 second interval? I honestly think a bigger battery will be your lowest volume solution. Please edit your question to include the requested information (don't reply in the comments).

Comment: If you're trying to energize a vaping coil with a button cell I don't think this will prove practical. Maybe a tiny lithium ion rechargable, but that would be a shopping problem.

Comment: At what *voltage*? At a few mV, yes. at 1.5 V, no. A capacitor or supercap would be larger than the button cell. However, if you just need a few mV, a step-down inverter would work.

Comment: Yes, it can be done. But not easily and certainly not in a small space. One of the larger common button batteries, a CR2032, has at best about 2000 Joules in it. And that's from a 3 V to a 2V (dead) output voltage range. That's maybe 800 Coulombs, total, at a guess. You need 5 Coulombs per event. So it would appear possible. But let's compare this with something else -- Estes igniters. These require the delivery of about 30 times less charge than you appear to need, to fire off a rocket. (That's the all-fire spec.) You want a LOT more. And the igniter problem is hard enough already.

Comment: Forget the supercap. For the size it takes you can increase the size of the battery. Look for high drain rate rechargable lithiums as used in micro-drones

Comment: @mkeith: Thanks for your response. yes, it can decay over time but should remain above 0.1v

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: Thanks for your response. It's a shape memory alloy wire, and I'm trying to heat it by passing current through it.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Thanks for your response. Can you suggest any step-down inverter? I can try that if it works. I tried BL8530 based boost converter and I got 1-3v with 150-180mA.

Comment: @Rehan please edit the question rather than reply to comments. When the wire is passing 500 mA, what is the voltage across the wire? Is it only 0.1 V?

Comment: @jonk: Thanks for this information, I'll have a look around the Estes igniters, I might found something from there. Thanks!

Comment: @mkeith: Thanks for your follow up. Yes, I edited the question as advised and the voltage can be between 0.1v and 1v. Which means it can be as low as 0.1v as far as the current is 500mA and above to activate the wire I'm testing.

Comment: @Neil_UK: Thanks for this advice. I appreciate that, but I'm unable to find any small scale high drain rate rechargeable lithium battery. The size constraints are 12mm diameter and 10mm length maximum. Can you suggest any product, if you came across? Or know any company which can make some on customized order?

Comment: @Rehan The huge elephant in the room is impedance matching and Webers. To match the impedance you need a transformer, operated in discontinuous mode. But the transformer needs to hold the energy. You are talking on the order of 10 Joules! At half an amp (assumed continuous), this is 20 Webers! Even with an iron core that can support 2 Tesla, that's 10 square meters of cross-section!! Not small. If you went air-core, which doesn't have a limit, you'd need to generate 200,000 Tesla in a 1 cm^2 cross-section! This is what's called "rocket science."

Comment: @Rehan on the Hobbyking.com website, I find a Z240S20C, Zippy 240 mAh 20C battery, volume 60% higher than you need, but will produce 4 amps. There's a company that would have the capability to custom make something that would fit. If you dropped your configuration constraint (went flat pack rather than cylindrical) you wouldn't have to compromise much on volume, and then you'd have something off the shelf. Maybe micro drones already use something that would fit and Zippy make them, why not approach them directly to.find out

Comment: @Neil_UK: Wow! Thanks a lot for sharing this. I'll get in touch with the company to look for customized solution. Thanks, much appreciated.